# How to open a python script with a constructor variable

Tags: python, linux, bash

So i've been at this one for a little while and cant seem to get it. Im trying to execute a python script via terminal and want to pass a string value with it. That way, when the script starts, it can check that value and act accordingly. Like this:

```
sudo python myscript.py mystring
```

How can i go about doing this. I know there's a way to start and stop a script using bash, but thats not really what im looking for. Any and all help accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following inside ur script:

```
import sys
arg1 = str(sys.argv[1])
print(arg1)
```

Comment: glad to be able to help you :)

Answer (score -2):

Since you are passing a string, you need to pass it in quotes:

```
sudo python myscript.py 'mystring'
```

Also, you shouldn't have to run it with sudo.

Comment: I do need to run it with sudo.. It's an RPi project controlling GPIO pins, therefore, sudo is necessary :)

Comment: You are mistaken about the need for quotations marks here. The quotations marks don't make it a string (it's already a string); they are only necessary to protect certain characters from being interpreted by the shell.